# Creating a Postgres database with JDBC Driver when starting a SpringBoot app?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

When I want to use a Mysql database in a Springboot app, I am able to create it on start via a string in properties similar to this:

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```

Nevertheless PostgreSQL seems to ignore this:

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```

Is there a way to create a PostgreSQL db on start of a SpringBoot app before Flyway attempts to initiate tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres doesn't support creating a database on demand via the JDBC URL. You can learn about what configuration is possible in the [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html).